# What does a return of 204 in Google SafeBrowsing mean?

Tags: google-api

If I send a request to Google SafeBrowsing for domain http://microsoft.com and the return code is 204, (correct URL but no return data), does that mean that the domain is "Good"?  Or "Unknown"?  Or "Not Bad"?

The documentation is not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Wikipedia

```
204 No Content
The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content.
Usually used as a response to a successful delete request
```

200 level responses all indicate success of some sort.  After looking at the Google documentation it appears that a 204 response means that the site is legitimate and not a phishing or malware site.

Comment: I do know what 204 indicates.  But why is google returning the 204 when requesting safebrowsing information about a particular domain?

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I couldn't find, in the Safebrowser docs where it gave the "success" vs "failure" examples.   On a weird note, I fed in a bunch of blacklisted websites from another source, and they came back as 204 also.  so have yet to test a "bad" malware.  Thanks for the help

Comment: cool, if my answer helped please choose it as the accepted answer.  thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible to trigger a bad response with GSB - I have also been feeding in malware sites and all I get is a 204 response, every single time.

Comment: I finally managed to trigger a 200 code by entering a link directly to an infected file. No idea what the actual file was just that it's listed as malware. The entire body of the response was "unwanted" which is actually listed in the docs.